# How to load Crystal Report in WPF C# using entity data model?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2

Guys

i try to load crystal report in WPF window using entity data model  but it doesn't load , how to load it ?

i used this tutorials but my enviroment is VS2012

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/crystal-report-viewer-in-wpf-part-1/

this is my code :

```
 using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
 using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
 private void crystalReportsViewer1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
        report.Load("CrystalReport1.rpt");
        using (cvmakerEntities1 db = new cvmakerEntities1())
        {
            report.SetDataSource(from c in db.cvs
             select new {c.Full_Name,c.Address,c.E_Mail,c.Activities,c.Birth_Day,c.Courses,c.Education,c.Experience,c.Gender,c.Mobile,c.Nationality,c.Occuptional_Field,c.Personnal_Website,c.photo,c.Skills,c.Tele});
        }
        crystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
    }
```

this is code in xml designer

```
<Window x:Class="CV_Maker.Report"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clnamespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer"
    Title="Report" Height="800" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <my:CrystalReportsViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="crystalReportsViewer1"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="769" Width="792" Loaded="crystalReportsViewer1_Loaded" />
</Grid>
```

what is the problem here ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are loading report inside CrystalReportViewer_Loaded

Set your report load inside Window_Loaded Event as the article states, and remove the Loaded event inside xaml code of CrystalReportViewer:

1) Remove Loaded property:

```
<my:CrystalReportsViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="crystalReportsViewer1"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="769" Width="792" Loaded="crystalReportsViewer1_Loaded" />
```

2) Add Window Loaded event:

```
<Window xmlns:Viewer="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer" ... Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

2) Rename event inside xaml.cs

from

```
private void crystalReportsViewer1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

to

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
...
}
```